# how to increase width of check box list item

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

How to increase the width of checkbox list item text,

I have more space on right side but the text is coming in multiple lines but not coming to right side.

and also it is possible to place the checkbox left to the text?

Thanks in advance

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server" Width="300px" ForeColor="Black" TextAlign="Right">
 <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="Invoice" ></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="20" Text="Payments"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="30" Text="General Ledger posting"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>



.chkBoxList td
{
   width:120px; /* or percent value: 25% */
}
```

where the list item 3 is coming in multiple lines, and i want to make it in a single line.

Comment: can you show your current html

Comment: As Optimus mentions there are many reasons this could be happening, without some sample HTML it would be impossible to determine the cause.

Comment: Hi i added my code snippet here, please check this once.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Py5xN/)

*HTML*

```
<div class="ques">Is it an animal?</div><div class="cb"><input type ="checkbox" value="yes" /></div>
<div class="ques">Is it an mineral?</div><div class="cb"><input type ="checkbox" value="yes" /></div>
<div class="ques">Is it an vegetable?</div><div class="cb"><input type ="checkbox" value="yes" /></div>
<div class="ques">Is it an fruit?</div><div class="cb"><input type ="checkbox" value="yes" /></div>
<div class="ques">Is it man-made?</div><div class="cb"><input type ="checkbox" value="yes" /></div>
```

*CSS*

```
.ques {width:66%;display:inline;float:left;}
.cb {width:33%;display:inline;float:left;}
```